# Get a tags in tag p

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to drop the code in a paragraph on every element it clicks on, but when I do that it returns [object html] to me.

How to display the tag in text (the tag itself)

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        text = target.textContent || target.innerText;   
        document.getElementsByClassName("html-tag-element-picker")[0].innerHTML=target;
        
}, false);
```

Comment: Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("html-tag-element-picker")).forEach(domnode => domnode.innerHTML=target)

Comment: Please include your HTML to help [demonstrate the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I want to show it as Html tags
like the
<span> </span>

Do not show the name of the tag. Show the tag itself as a tag

Comment: @DovRine wow and they say jquery is dead... `$(".html-tag-element-picker").html(target)`

Comment: `[object html]` means you have an object, you need to use one of its properties.  If I knew nothing else about js, I would guess that you want to change `=target` to `=text`

Comment: @freedomn-m: the object is a collection of domNodes b/c document.getElementsByClassName returns a collection of domNodes. This collection does not have Array.prototype methods which is why I wrote my first comment the way that I did. I don't understand your jQuery reference.

Comment: @DovRine just pointing out that all your array.from/getel/foreach => `$`.  Nothing "wrong" with what you wrote, just too loquacious for me.

Comment: @freedomn-m: There is a big difference between vanilla js and jQuery. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want to display the element tag a user clicks in your element, something like this?
Or maybe you want everything, updated answer:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
    text = target.textContent || target.innerText;
  document.getElementsByClassName("html-tag-element-picker")[0].innerHTML =e.target.outerHTML;
}, false);
```

```css
span {
background: red;
}
p {
background: green;
}
```

```html
<xmp class="html-tag-element-picker"></xmp>

<span>span el</span>
<p>p el</p>
```